# call a method from an outside class (not activity) to execute when fragment is opened

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I've tried to find an answer on here. I think that I'm not interpreting the answers correctly but just in case here is my situtation. I am using a button from a main activity to open a fragment. Once the fragment is opened I want an outside class to execute a math program and display the results in the fragment. I can get the result to display in the fragment but I cant get the math program to execute. I know how to call a method from an outside class but I'm not sure where to put in. Would I put it in the fragment or the main activity?

My first attempt was use something like: 
Mercury test = new Mercury();
test.mCalculation;

That works but I'm not sure how to use this.

Here is the Main Activity:

```
public class MainActivity extends     
AppCompatActivity implements 
TestFragment.OnFragmentInteractionListener {

Button btnFavourites;
Mercury mercury;


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    btnFavourites = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_test);

    btnFavourites.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {


            android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager fragmentManager = MainActivity.this.getSupportFragmentManager();
            android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();

            TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();

            fragmentTransaction.add(R.id.frame_layout, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
            btnFavourites.setVisibility(View.GONE);

        }
    });



}

@Override
public void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri) {

}
```

}

Here is the fragment:

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
// TODO: Rename parameter arguments, choose    
names that match
// the fragment initialization parameters,    
e.g.     ARG_ITEM_NUMBER
private static final String ARG_PARAM1 = "param1";
private static final String ARG_PARAM2 = "param2";
private TextView planetLongitude;
private TextView planetLatitude;

// TODO: Rename and change types of parameters
private String mParam1;
private String mParam2;

Mercury test;

private OnFragmentInteractionListener mListener;

public TestFragment() {
    // Required empty public constructor
}

/**
 * Use this factory method to create a new instance of
 * this fragment using the provided parameters.
 *
 * @param param1 Parameter 1.
 * @param param2 Parameter 2.
 * @return A new instance of fragment TestFragment.
 */
// TODO: Rename and change types and number of parameters
public static TestFragment newInstance(String param1, String param2) {
    TestFragment fragment = new TestFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM1, param1);
    args.putString(ARG_PARAM2, param2);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    if (getArguments() != null) {
        mParam1 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM1);
        mParam2 = getArguments().getString(ARG_PARAM2);



    }





}

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // Inflate the layout for this fragment
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_test, container, false);




         planetLongitude = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.latitude);

        planetLongitude.setText("" + Mercury.getLonecl());




        return view;
    }


// TODO: Rename method, update argument and hook method into UI event
public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if (context instanceof OnFragmentInteractionListener) {
        mListener = (OnFragmentInteractionListener) context;
    } else {
        throw new RuntimeException(context.toString()
                + " must implement OnFragmentInteractionListener");
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

/**
 * This interface must be implemented by activities that contain this
 * fragment to allow an interaction in this fragment to be communicated
 * to the activity and potentially other fragments contained in that
 * activity.
 * <p>
 * See the Android Training lesson <a href=
 * "http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/communicating.html"
 * >Communicating with Other Fragments</a> for more information.
 */
public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    // TODO: Update argument type and name
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}
```

}

Here is the outclass I want to execute when the fragment is opened:

```
public class Mercury {

public static double xv = 0;
public static double yv = 0;
private static double lonecl = 0;
private static double latecl = 0;
public static double N = 48.3313 + 3.24587e-5 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
public static double i = 7.0047 + 5.00e-8 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
public static double w = 29.1241 + 1.0144e-5 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
public static double a = 0.387098;
public static double e = 0.205635 + 5.59e-10 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
public static double M = 168.6562 + 4.0923344368 * PlanetVariableCalculations.getd2();
public static double w1 = N + w;
public static double L = M + w1;
public static double q = a * (1 - e);
public static double Q = a * (1 + e);
public static double E0 = 0;
public static double P = Math.pow(a, 1.5);


   private void mCalculation() {
    if (M < 0) {
        while (M < 0) {
            M = M + 360;
        }

    } else if (M > 360) {
        while (M > 360) {
            M = M - 360;
        }
    }
    EccentricAnomaly(M);
}

private void EccentricAnomaly(double M) {


    double angleInRadian = Math.toRadians(M);
    double E = M + e * Math.sin(angleInRadian) * (1.0 + e * Math.cos(angleInRadian));
    if (e > 0.06) {
    E0 = E;
    double angleInRadianE = Math.toRadians(E0);
    double E1 = E0 - (E0 - e * Math.sin(angleInRadianE) - M) / (1 - e * Math.cos(angleInRadianE));
    while (E1 != E0) {
        E1 = E0;
        E1 = E0 - (E0 - e * Math.sin(angleInRadianE) - M) / (1 - e * Math.cos(angleInRadianE));
    }

    xv = Math.cos(E1) - e;
    yv = Math.sqrt(1.0 - e * e) * Math.sin(E1);

    //} else{
    xv = Math.cos(E) - e;
    yv = Math.sqrt(1.0 - e * e) * Math.sin(E);
}

double v = Math.atan2(yv, xv);
double r = Math.sqrt(xv * xv + yv * yv);

double xh = r * (Math.cos(N) * Math.cos(v + w) - Math.sin(N) * Math.sin(v + w) * Math.cos(i));
double yh = r * (Math.sin(N) * Math.cos(v + w) - Math.cos(N) * Math.sin(v + w) * Math.cos(i));
double zh = r * (Math.sin(v + w) * Math.sin(i));
double lacteclsqr = Math.sqrt(xh * xh + yh * yh);

lonecl = 2+2;
latecl = Math.atan2(zh,lacteclsqr );


}

public static double getLonecl(){
    return lonecl;
}

public static double getLatecl(){
    return latecl;
}
```

}

Comment: you can try calling that method in onCreateView method of the fragment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll try to answer this although I'm not completely sure what you mean by "I cant get the math program to execute".

I can already say that you probably need to read a bit more about what the `static` keyword means, maybe start [here](https://www.javatpoint.com/static-keyword-in-java). You also need to determine if you really need to create an instance.

If your class doesn't retain information and only does calculations and return a value, you should probably make it static.

```
double lonEcl = Mercury.computeLonEcl();
```

I think your problem is that the method `private void mCalculation()` is **private**, meaning it is only accessible within the class `Mercury`. You could replace `private` by `public` and use it via instance like this:

```
Mercury instance = new Mercury();
instance.mCalculation();
instance.getLonEcl();
```

Also, you should make those *constants* in your class `private static final...` or make them public if you need them outside of the class.

Comment: This answered the question. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of things here.

First.

You don't open a fragment. You add, remove, show, or hide a fragment.

Unless you are using a DialogFragment, but that is different.

Second.

Your helper class has no reason to retain an instance. So there is no reason to do so. Make your methods static in the math class and access them like

`Mercury.doMyMathProblem(args...)`

Now if you are saying "hey, I still want to use an instance". Well then you can either do a singleton if you only need one for the whole app, or you can simply new it up as needed like.

```
new Mercury().doMyMathProblems(args...)
```

If you need to store it in an instance variable in your fragment, then simply create it in your onCreate method.

```
onCreate(){
    mMercuryInstance = new Mercury()
}

onButtonClick(){
    Int answer = mMercuryInstance.doMyMathProblem(args...)
}
```

Of course this is just pseudo code, but should get the point across.